# EPPlus Changing Border Color of cells

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm trying to change the cell border color on a selected range. Couldn't find any other styles for cell borders other than for the weights of the borders as follows:

```
range.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
range.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
range.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
range.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to sent border colors on different parts of the cells you can do it like this:

```
range.Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
range.Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(Color.Green);
range.Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(Color.Blue);
range.Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(Color.Yellow);
```

`SetColor` can take any kind of `System.Drawing.Color`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its working now, clearly I wasn't paying attention that there was a .color property after the third property.

Answer (score 8):

you can change the border style and color using this code

```
range.Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Medium, System.Drawing.Color.Blue);
```

Comment: This works too, but I needed a solution that adds border to all sides per cell as what Ernie's solution dictates. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6):

```
            using (ExcelRange range = worksheet.Cells["A1:H1"])
            {
                range.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                range.Style.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
                range.Style.VerticalAlignment = ExcelVerticalAlignment.Center;
                range.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                range.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.White);

                range.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                range.Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(Color.Red);
                range.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                range.Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(Color.Green);
                range.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                range.Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(Color.Green);
                range.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                range.Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(Color.Green);
            }
```

[image: The final output will come as shown here]